# Issue with Running Android Program on Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I downloaded complete *Android Environment Development Environment Snapshots* from [marakana.com](http://marakana.com/support/android_setup.html). I start eclipse and create new Android project. On the `Run Configurations`, i created New Configuration to run the application, and set the Target to `Automatic` and select the AVD that appropriate to run the application. But, when i click on the run icon, it starts the new emulator, and after some minutes, just android emulator be ran and my application doesn't run on it.

What do i do to solve the running problem and run my project on emulator ?

**NOTE 1**: Console outputs :

```
[2012-03-07 16:03:49 - New] ------------------------------
[2012-03-07 16:03:49 - New] Android Launch!
[2012-03-07 16:03:49 - New] adb is running normally.
[2012-03-07 16:03:49 - New] Performing com.android.example.NewActivity activity launch
[2012-03-07 16:03:53 - New] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Device'
[2012-03-07 16:04:00 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Unable to create sensors port: Unknown error
```

**NOTE 2**: My Program Source:

```
package com.android.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class NewActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: Please show us your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Can you find the Application on your device and start it from the launcher?

Answer (score 0):

To start an Activity it needs an intent-filter like this:

```
<activity android:name=".NewActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Depending on your package name you can start it from the command line like this:

```
adb shell am start -n your.package.name/.NewActivity
```